# Windows Service to Watch the Downloads Directory for Files in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am fairly new to the Windows world, as most of my primary development is with UNIX systems. A specific request from a customer came in and asked if I could write a windows service to watch the Downloads folder for any downloaded content, and move it to their Documents folder. For some reason they didn't want to just change their default download directory on their browser.

So to give the customer what they asked I thought I would give it a shot. Here is my attempt:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        watch();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    String path = null;
    private void watch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        path = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        String pUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        String directoryName = Path.Combine(pUser, "Documents"); ;
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
        if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        List<String> MyFiles = Directory
                           .GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string file in MyFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            // to remove name collusion
            if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
                mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
        }
    }
```

I tested my code in debug mode and when the service is running and I go to download a file, the download fails. Visual Studio then pops up with this error:

`"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."`

The error is thrown on:

`mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);`

How can I fix this?

Comment: why don't you acquire the lock before moving the file , that way even if the file is still being downloaded you can wait till that finishes and the move it , of course you can make if perf better by trying the failed files after the first attempt and just taking lock on those. You will need to wrap it with try/catch for the first time

Comment: @loneshark99 what your describing makes sense, but I'm unfamiliar with C#. I just added a try/catch condition, which I should've done to begin with. Can you please elaborate on the locking?

Comment: Also do you really need a Windows service , you could just use robocopy and sync at regular time interval  as a scheduled job

Answer (score 0):

Your download begins and a temporary file is created in the downloads folder which begins to receive the download stream. As soon as the temporary file is created however, your mover application attempts to intercept and move the file which is obviously locked by another process because the download client is still writing to it.
Perhaps you could cache a list of files in the download folder along with file size and check on it to make sure the size isn't changing before you do the move. You could also exclude known extensions associated with downloading. Eg. *.temp, *.downloading
As you are dealing with a live file system where the user could lock a file at any time, you may also want to deal with locked file exceptions a bit more gracefully.